# opencv_python.libs folder is missing whenever I build opencv-python

Tags: ffmpeg, opencv, python-wheel, python

I have installed **opencv-python** using a wheel file.
When I inspect the wheel file I see it contains a folder called **opencv_python.libs** which contains all the needed shared object files such as ffmpeg (libavcodec etc) and Qt (libQt etc) .so files.

I have also built **opencv-python** and have created my own wheel file by running the following commmand:

```
pip wheel . --verbose
```

When I inspect the output **opencv_python-4.4.0.46-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl**  file I see that there is no **opencv_python.libs** folder.
I have also built ffmpeg so I guess I need to 'point' it to it somehow?

What do I need to do to include all the needed files in this **opencv_python.libs** folder?